# Respuesta entre java Spring y JQuery o Ajax

Tags: java, jquery, spring

estoy aprendiendo Spring en java, ya tenia conocimientos en java jsp y ya sabia como enviar y recivir respuestas de JQuery o Ajax a un controlador en java y recibir respuesta de java En JQuery y en Spring cambian varias cosas como podria realizar esto ??

Lo estoy intentando asi pero no funciona nose como debo hacerlo ya que en spring los request o response.getWriter que usaba para responder a JQuery desde un servelt lo hacia asi en spring nose como es.

```
 function enviarNombres() {
                nombres = document.getElementById('nombres').value;

                $.post("home.htm", {nombres: nombres}, function (respuesta) {
                 console.log(respuesta);
                });
            }
```

java class controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "home.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String agregarUsuario(@RequestParam(value = "nombres") String nombres) {

//        response.setContentType("text/plain"); esto lo usaba para que funcionara bn la respuesta
//        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); pero en spring esto no sirve

        System.out.println(nombres);

      

        return "respuesta";

    }
```

Comment: ¿Qué error te da? ¿Cómo tienes anotada la clase Controller?

Comment: @Pablo Lozano hola pablo , error no me da y cuando envio por post llega bien con sus variable super bn no hay error solo que no me envia reapuesta a JQuery con el return nose si asi se responde desde java a JQuery y el paquete se llama ( Controller ) y la clase 
Controlador  se llama Usuario y en el servlet.dispatcher es <bean name"controlador" class="Controller.Usuario " /> como te digo los parametros los recibe bien pero la respuesta no llega a JQuery nose si debo agregar algo mas nose y he visto videos y lo hacen como lo hago y otros  lo hacen anotando por xml

Comment: Si no hay error, mira en la consola del navegador la llamada y qué respuesta obtienes

Comment: Ya en la consola del navegador ya mire pero no llega la repuesta que envio desde el controlador nose porque nose si se debe agregar algo que indica que envia texto plano como se hacia en los servlets con response.setContentType("text/plain");

Comment: Prueba a poner la anotación @ResponseBody a ese método

Comment: Me sirvio con @ResponseBody muchas gracias Pablo

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que está pasando es que esperas que el String que devuelve el método de tu controller sea lo que se recibe en tu llamada AJAX, pero no es así a menos que definas el controlador como `@RestController` o en cada método añadas la anotación `@ResponseBody`: Por defecto lo de devuelve el método es usado para localizar el JSP en el que se delega la generación de la respuesta (generalmente HTML), pero con la anotación `@ResponseBody` le estás diciendo a Spring que lo que devuelve tu método es el cuerpo de tu respuesta:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UsuariosController {

    @ResponseBody
    @PostMapping("")
    public String agregarUsuario() { ...}
}
```

La anotación `@RestController` en la clase indica que este controller no usa el patrón MVC y que se está aplicando un estilo REST, por lo que es como poner `@ResponseBody` a todos los métodos:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UsuariosController {

    @PostMapping("")
    public String agregarUsuario() { ...}
}
```